# How to successfully route envoy to my second service?

Tags: microservices, envoyproxy

I am trying to deploy 2 services by using the envoy front proxy configuration from [envoy github page](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/tree/master/examples/front-proxy)

My first service is the main site which should work under “/”  and the second service is back office administration that should work under “/admin”. The problem starts when I declare the prefix of my first service as “/”. After that Envoy doesn’t route traffic to my admin service at all.

my front-envoy.yaml is:

```
static_resources:
 listeners:
 - address:
     socket_address:
       address: 0.0.0.0
       port_value: 80
   filter_chains:
   - filters:
     - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
       config:
         codec_type: auto
         stat_prefix: ingress_http
         route_config:
           name: local_route
           virtual_hosts:
           - name: backend
             domains:
             - “*”
             routes:
             - match:
                 prefix: “/”
               route:
                 cluster: service1
             - match:
                 prefix: “/admin”
               route:
                 cluster: service2
         http_filters:
         - name: envoy.router
           config: {}
 clusters:
 - name: service1
   connect_timeout: 0.25s
   type: strict_dns
   lb_policy: round_robin
   http2_protocol_options: {}
   hosts:
   - socket_address:
       address: service1
       port_value: 80
 - name: service2
   connect_timeout: 0.25s
   type: strict_dns
   lb_policy: round_robin
   http2_protocol_options: {}
   hosts:
   - socket_address:
       address: service2
       port_value: 80
admin:
 access_log_path: “/dev/null”
 address:
   socket_address:
     address: 0.0.0.0
     port_value: 8001
```

Please advice.

Comment: Your config looks fine - it should match `/admin` and forward it to service2, however, it'll include `/admin` as part of the path. Does service2 have a handler for `/admin`? If not, you'll have to rewrite the prefix before forwarding it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you have "/" as the first **prefix** matcher, "/" as a prefix will match with all the requests, it will match "/" requests as well as the "/admin" requests. Change the order of your matches to have "/admin" first and then "/". It should work fine.